# Forgotten word meaning susceptability to direction

Tags: experimental-physics, terminology

A little over a year ago, I encountered a descriptive word with respect to experimental physics, describing the phenomenon in which calibrating an instrument from one direction will yield a different result than calibrating it from another. For example, I might have a laser, and I adjust the output frequency by increasing or decreasing current. If I attempt to reach the desired frequency from below, the current I end up with will be different from what I would have obtained if I had attempted to reach the desired frequency from a high current (due to temperature effects etc.).

Can anybody know what word relates to this? I realize my description and recollection is not perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually this is called "hysteresis" - a bit of "memory" of the last state (definition from Google):

> the phenomenon in which the value of a physical property lags behind changes in the effect causing it, as for instance when magnetic induction lags behind the magnetizing force.

It can also (in the case of mechanical instruments) be known as "backlash". For example this plays in a micrometer or objects with gearing. When you turn it in one direction, you can then turn it a little bit the other way without changing the distance between the jaws. This implies you always need to approach your measurement in the same direction to avoid adding noise to the measurement.

Comment: Hysteresis is the word I was trying to get to, thank you! And thank you also for "backlash". (It turns out neither quite matches the specific issue I have, though.)